# Delphi и VFP9

Tags: delphi

Как в DELPHI7 работать с файлами VFP9?
Там что-то с алиасами -пробую в BDE добавить алиас "vfp" для
доступа к табл. VFP9, даю ему type Microsoft FoxPro VFP driver
задаю еще не совсем понятные параметры,
потом в Database Desktop пробую создать новую таблицу,
беру Table type = Microsoft FoxPro VFP driver, задаю
одно поле, на сохранении запрашивает Database, User Name, password
и при любых введенных значениях выдает Invalid configuration parameter
Alias vfp.
Извиняюсь за быть  может, дремучесть, когда-то, лет 7 тому
как-то что-то такое делал, забыл напрочь. Будьте здоровы,ЮСоколов.

Answer (score 1):

Формат DBF для DELPHI/BDE существенно отличается от DBF VFP9. Я вижу (и пользовался этим) 2 пути. Первый - ODBC. Второй - на просторах DELPHI в I-net'е есть компонент для работы с DBF VFP9. К сожалению не смог у себя его найти. Синтаксис напоминает FOX, но почти все сделано с помощью функций.